# Writing long stream of characters to text file QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, text, serial-port

I am trying to write a program that will create a text file and write a stream of characters that I read from a serial port. I am just trying to understand how I can get the code to continuously write the data and not overwrite the previously written data because I will need it to keep every character sent. I wrote this code as a test but I can't get it to continuously write the text. It writes it once and then stops.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
int main() {
int test = 0;
while(test < 2){
QString filename = "Data.txt";
QFile file(filename);
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << "one thing to test" << endl;
    test++;
  }
 }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, opening with `QIODevice::ReadWrite` will truncate the file on write. According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qiodevice.html), `QIODevice::Append` will open the file for writing at the end of the file.

If you really want to **both** read and write, you could `QIODevice::seek()` to the end of the file before writing.

Comment: Perfect. I can't believe I overlooked such a small thing. By changing ReadWrite to Append it opens up the file and adds the text instead of overwriting once. Thanks!